# Extract and save as csv files based on specified timeframe

Tags: r

Below is my dataset example saved as a csv file. Is it possible to extract them and save as several csv files based on specified timeframe.

For example:

The specified timeframes are:

daytime: 07:30 (same date) to 20:30 (same date)
nighttime: 21:30 (same date) to 06:30 (next date).

After the extraction, datasets are save as csv files based on this filename format:
daytime: "date"-day
daytime: "date"-night

"date" is the date from the timestamp.

Thanks for your help.

```
    timestamp   c3.1    c3.2    c3.3    c3.4    c3.5    c3.6    c3.7    c3.8    c3.9    c3.10   c3.11   c3.12
8/13/15 15:43   1979.84 1939.6  2005.21 1970    1955.55 1959.82 1989    2001.12 2004.38 1955.75 1958.75 1986.53
8/13/15 15:44   1979.57 1939.64 2005.14 1970.4  1956.43 1958.56 1989.7  2000.78 2004.53 1954.9  1959.76 1986.18
8/13/15 15:45   1979.32 1938.92 2004.52 1970.21 1955.75 1960.12 1989.07 2001.47 2003.7  1955.32 1958.94 1985.79
8/13/15 15:46   1979.33 1939.7  2004.66 1971.25 1955.89 1958.27 1989.24 2000.86 2003.92 1955.29 1959.25 1985.49
```

Comment: Use `read.csv()`, subset the data frame into two time frames, then use `write.csv()` to get it back out to disk.

Comment: what is subset the data frame into two time frames?

Comment: Do you want two files for each day, night and day?  It might be easier for you to do this in Excel.

Comment: your day time and night time will miss records since the time periods don't match. And for clarification, just an indicator which record is day and which is night and split on this?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `dat` is your data:

```
## The date-time format in the data set
format <- "%m/%d/%y %H:%M"

## Convert date-time to POSIXct
timestamp <- as.POSIXct(dat$timestamp, format = format)

## First and last dates in the data 
first <- as.Date(min(timestamp))
last <- as.Date(max(timestamp)) 
## The start of day and night timeframes
start.day <- paste(first, "07:30")
start.night <- paste(first - 1, "20:30") ## first night timeframe starts the day before 
end <- paste(last + 1, "20:30") 

## The breakpoints, assuming that day is 7:30-20:30 and nigth 20:31-7:29 (i.e. no missing records)
breaks <- sort.POSIXlt(c(seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(start.day), as.POSIXct(end), by= "day"),
                         seq.POSIXt(as.POSIXct(start.night), as.POSIXct(end), by= "day")))
## The corresponding labels
labels <- head(paste0(as.Date(breaks), c("-night", "-day")), - 1)

## Add column with timeframe
dat$timeframe <-cut.POSIXt(timestamp, breaks = breaks, labels = labels)


## Save csv files
for(x in levels(dat$timeframe)) {
  subset <- dat[dat$timeframe == x, ]
  subset$timeframe <- NULL ## Remove the timeframe column
  if(nrow(subset) > 0) write.csv(subset, file = paste0(x, ".csv"))
}
```